# Ideal number of files per folder for large sets of files

Tags: filesystems, repository, storage

I am currently in the process of designing a simple repository that uses the file system to store documents. There is the future potential for millions of files and the strategy that I want to use to map an ID to a location on disk is a means of hashing the ID and using part of the hash to determine the directory it should live in.

A common operation will be reading through all of the files per folder and any of it's nested folders.

> My question is: is there an ideal ratio of files per directory? I have
>   the means to control this ratio via the ID -> location algorithm. Any
>   data to back answers up would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is what you're worrying about, this will depend the
type of filesystem you are using.  Older filesystems like
[ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2#File_system_limits) kept
directory entries in a linear list.  Looking up a particular file in a
directory could be very expensive.

Modern filesystems such as ext4,
[btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs_design#Directories),
[xfs](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Foss.sgi.com%2Fprojects%2Fxfs%2Fpapers%2Fxfs_filesystem_structure.pdf&ei=0QngVLbFJce0ogTq54HABQ&usg=AFQjCNEn2YBQNThENsm6yFaNPZnVNptHjg&sig2=7Puc2BXxS4GosD3xrYTnKA&bvm=bv.85970519,d.cGU)
and others typically have indexed directories, the access time of a
single file in a huge directory isn't going to be appreciably
different from accessing a single file in a small directory.  In fact,
spreading millions of files over many subdirectories may give you
slower lookup performance than having them all in a single directory!

If you are writing your own software that will do a lot of linear
scans of the entire set of files or access individual files by name,
it probably doesn't matter which way you go about it (as long as you
[access it the right
way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120077/the-ls-command-is-not-working-for-a-directory-with-a-huge-number-of-files/120078#120078).

I would worry more about managing the file system outside of the
application.  Typical system utilities (like ls) may use readdir() or
linear scans of directories.  To prevent the sysadmins from having
terrible headaches when diagnosing issues within the directory
structure, I'd go with something agreeably bushy, and 10k-20k entries
per directory (assuming indexed directories) would work.

When choosing your layout, you may wish to watch out for limits on the
number of subdirectories allowed per directory (i.e. 64000 on ext4).